# Excel formula to return last xth numeric value from row

Tags: excel

I have a data set like this:

```
a   1       2   3       5       6   7
b       5       1   3   4           
c   7   4       3   2       6       
d   1   2   3                       7
e   7   5               5   6   7
```

which i want to transform in excel to only show the last 4 numeric values for each row, i.e.

```
a   3   5   6   7
b   5   1   3   4
c   4   3   2   6
d   1   2   3   7
e   5   5   6   7
```

Ive managed to use `=INDEX(row1,MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,row1))` which correctly returns the last value (i.e. 7 for row1 in this case) but how could i get the 2nd last, 3rd last, 4th last etc?

Comment: I'm a little confused about the layout of your data... Are there really letters on each row? Or are those supposed to be your columns?

Comment: This would be a lot easier if you could transpose your data. Can you? If not, is a VBA solution acceptable?

Comment: I should be able to transpose it - what would the solution be then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I managed to figure out how to do this generically for any digits:

Say your original numerical data is in cells `D5:N9`.

*OPTIONAL:*
If any of the rows of data contain the same value twice create a copy in cells `D13:N17` which amends duplicates slightly by using in `D13` and dragging to fill
`=IF(D5="","",D5+0.0001*(COUNTIF($D5:D5,D5)-1))`

Then in cells `A13:A17` enter values `13`,`14`,`15`,`16`,`17`
and in cells `A20:A29` enter values `D`, `E`, `F`, `G`, `H`, `I`, `J`, `K`, `L`, `M`

In Cell `D20` you can return the last from row `13` value using:
`=LOOKUP(9.99999999E+307,D13:N13)`
and copy this down for each row.

In Cell `E20` you can return the 2nd last entry using 
`=LOOKUP(9.99999999E+307,$D13:INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(INDEX($A$20:$A$29,MATCH(D20,$D13:$N13,0)-1),$A13)))`
and copy this down for each row and drag it across to `H24` to fill in all the values for 3rd last, 4th last and 5th last for each row.

Answer (score 1):

With `a` in A1, in M1 copied across and down to suit:

```
=MID(RIGHT($B1&$C1&$D1&$E1&$F1&$G1&$H1&$I1&$J1,4),COLUMN()-12,1)
```

then hide ColumnsB:L.

(Only works for single digits, as shown. Recent versions of Excel may offer better options.)

Comment: Way more elegant than the monstrosity I came up with. For 2016 you could use `TEXTJOIN`: `=MID(RIGHT(TEXTJOIN("",TRUE,$B1:$J1),4),COLUMN()-12,1)`

Comment: Thanks pnuts, this works really well for my example above, what I failed to mention is that in my actual use case some of the numbers are >10 and some may even be >100 in which case that method doesnt work - any ideas on extending it to non-single digit numbers?